# Babel cannot find module core/splash Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have a Node.js project written by another developer that I am having trouble executing due to Babel being unable (probably) to trace correct paths for module imports:

There is a line in the main.js that reads  `import Splash from 'core/splash'`.
The project's main.js file is located in path `"project_name/webapp/core/main.js"`
The `"project_name/webapp/core/"` directory also contains a file named `splash.js` but as far as I understand it is not a package since there is no package.json associated with it. Am I right to assume that the import line above is trying to load this file but is failing due to it not being a package or is it simply because I am not understanding the directory structure correctly?
I am executing the `main.js` using command `babel-node .\webapp\core\main.js`

The exact error I am receiving is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'core/splash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Node.js version v8.11.3,
babel-cli version ^6.26.0,
Babel installed globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify an absolute path in your import statement (i.e. `core/splash`), Node.js will assume you are referencing an npm module in the `node_modules` directory.

In this example, it will look for a module named `core` that contains a file `splash.js`.

If you want to import a module that is part of your own source code (not installed from the `npm` registry), use a relative path instead.

If `main.js` and `splash.js` are located in the same directory `core`, the correct import statement is:

```
import Splash from './splash'
```

The leading `./` tells Node.js: “This is a relative path, starting in the directory of the current module.”

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try this shortly, but there are at least twenty other imports with absolute paths similar to this one. I am trying to run this project on Windows but I know its original developer worked on Linux. Am I right to assume that on Linux the imports with absolute paths would work differently than they do on Windows? (these imports were made by the previous developer)

Comment: No, the operating system should not make a difference.

Comment: it is possible that your predecessor used the NODE_PATH environment variable to achieve absolute paths in import statements, as explained here: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#5-the-environment – setting env vars works differently on Linux and Windows, hence the problem you're facing